# Python OpenCV Error: Current thread is not the object's thread

Tags: python, qt, opencv

I'm having an error running simple code using cv2 module.

It's just:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('sudoku.png',0)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

And it fails with the following error:

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1b74720) is not the object's thread (0x1e57d70).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1b74720)
```

I googled this error and tried a lot of things but it doesn't help. I tried installing without pip, I tried using step-by-step installation (from official OpenCV) but nothing helps.

When I run:

```
cv2.__version__
```

It returns 3.4.3

Comment: [Is this the complete error message? No traceback, no line numbers?](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/)

Comment: yeah, I only got 3 lines of code and it's everything that appears in the console

Comment: Also, which `cv2` package are you using -- the official one or [`opencv-python`](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)? Which OS and Python implementation? Are you using this from an interactive console or ipython/jupyter?

Comment: I tried using the official one but it doesn't work, so I had to install opencv-python. OS is Ubuntu, I'm running the code via PyCharm but the same error I receive when I run it from the console

Comment: Are you running python2 or python3, I found similar issues on google but probably you also find them and tried suggestions. A temporary solution is to use matplotlib instead of opencv imshow.

Comment: A sure-fire solution is to build `opencv` from source and run the code under debugger. Then you'll see what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: Please see the updated answer below.

Comment: Did you try the LD_DEBUG line that I added to the answer below?   Did it give you some more information about the bug?    Note that on my system this group of bugs turns out to be related to a low level system-wide library that has to be updated.

Comment: Triggered by another library install, I reinstalled a slightly newer/older OpenCV python library, thus seemingly regaining for OpenCV the version compatibility with that qt lib that I have from other libraries installed.

Answer (score 24):

As noted already, the basis for this problem is discussed in [opencv-python issue 46](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/46), and results from the duplication of the following libraries both on the host and the opencv-python distro **libQtDBus** **libQtCore** and **libQtGui**.

It has been lately addressed in the newest release of opencv-python. It is not a fix to the source code, rather the fix is to force **pip** to compile the newly available source via

```
pip install --no-binary opencv-python opencv-python
```

This will cause opencv-python to use the same libraries as the host, so the conflict no longer exists.

Comment: Be advised that with the latest opencv-python this compilation may take a somewhat long while

Comment: @matanster agreed, I was surprised to see that it took my PC Ryzen 7 3700X 64GB RAM, NVIDIA 2080Ti around 20-30 mins...... what a library~!

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to use `sudo pip install --no-binary opencv-python opencv-python` while running the python code, I had to use `sudo python3 cv_qt_file.py`. It didn't work without `sudo` for me. Any way I can fix the non-sudo version?

Comment: @OzoneX is your user in the `video` group? Without that, some stuff works, some doesn't, and the failures can be surprising

Comment: @ChrisH What do you mean by `video` group? I'm the admin single user, so making use of sudo while needed sometimes.

Comment: @OzoneX I have a similar setup (though with a secondary account that isn't used).  But there's a group called "video" (`grep 'video' /etc/group`) and I wasn't in it.  Since adding myself to that group, I don't need sudo for some of the V4L/openCV stuff I used to need it for.  Other video stuff has always worked without needing to be in the group

Answer (score 12):

I haven't spent the time to fully appreciate this problem, but as I understand this is caused by multiple conflicting versions of some plugin in the environment. I tried installing building opencv-python but there were errors with that approach. Another suggestion is to change your import order, but I've had mixed success with that, and I couldn't get it to work on a project today.

But I found a workaround that worked for me. Install `opencv-python-headless` instead of `opencv-python`. This will avoid installing the conflicting plugins. It may not work for you depending on what features of opencv you need.

```
$ pip uninstall opencv-python
$ pip install opencv-python-headless
```

Answer (score 9):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/46) posted on the OpenCV GitHub, this is a known issue that the developer states is damn near impossible to fix. It is apparently caused by a conflict in any Qt installations on the system with the Qt that is shipped with OpenCV. There are some suggestions floating around to remove the `libqt5x11extras5` package from the system. This may fix it for some but **anyone running these libraries on a Linux distribution that uses a window manager based on Qt will render their desktop environment unusable by removing this package** (having tried it myself).

You can try building OpenCV from source using the `WITH_GTK=ON` option when running `cmake` which will use GTK instead of Qt, circumventing the conflict. However, this is hard to make use of in Python when using virtual environments.

Comment: Current hope seems to be that the issue will go away when OpenCV moves to Qt 5 in its next release.

Comment: Still the same problem in version 4.4.0.

Comment: @AndreasK. yep, I don't think they feel like fixing it. It's been three years.

Comment: It's not necessarily that at all.   On my system it was traced to a blas libary, and updating that blas library makes the error go away.    So, it seems like it is not entirely correct, despite winning 6 votes.

Comment: @DrM if my answer is a solution for some people but not others, is it not still a viable solution?

Comment: You could state that a little more clearly.  Rather than "this is ...", say "on some machine this may be ..." .    But even so, I would try to reproduce it and turn on some debugging to verify where it is coming from, before making even a qualified proclamation.   As I report in my answer, I am running that same code for the opencv gui, and after fixing blas, I have no problem.

Comment: @DrM `This may fix it for some...`

Comment: See waTeim's answer.  That is consistent with the observation that updating a library appears to solve it.   So again, it is not a qt problem and the developer's not is in error.

Answer (score 3):

The error was fixed on my system, by simply updating one library.

To find out where it is coming from, assuming Linux, try the following,

```
LD_DEBUG=files python -c "import cv2"
```

or,

```
LD_DEBUG=files python -c "import cv2 ; img = cv2.imread('myimage.png',0) ; cv2.imshow('image',img) ; cv2.waitKey(0)"
```

On my machine, it failed in one of the blas libraries.  I updated that library and the code now runs without error.

This is an old bug you can find it discussed in a number of online communities.

My test code is as follows.   Notably the error has not reoccurred, and apparently has nothing to do with Qt.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('sudoku.png',0)

cv2.imshow('image',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I've noticed that the problem occurs at 'cv2.imshow' function because my code is everything that I pasted in here.

Comment: @Desiigner  I am curious, did you try my suggestion, and did it fix your problem?

Comment: @DrM So I tried your code, and it works, no errors at all. I'm getting the original error when running Jupyter Notebook, so I think I should not run the notebook. I also found I can use the notebook as long as I leave out waitKey()

Comment: I have the problem with python 3.8 Ubuntu 18.04 and when running the LD_DEBUG I get " 26295: initialize program: python
     26295: 
     26295: 
     26295: transferring control: python
     26295: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
     26295: 
     26295: calling fini: python [0]
     26295: 
". After pip install opencv-python in base conda environment I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, a fresh environment install fixed the issue. For `Conda` and environment name `<env-name>`:

```
$ conda create --name <env-name>
$ conda activate <env-name>
$ conda install python=3.11
$ pip install opencv-python
```

To reproduce the issue before and see the fix after, you can run:

```
import cv2
import os
img = cv2.imread('sample.jpg')
cv2.imshow("my_window", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you run into a less important, but annoying message similar to below saying invalid style, then just set the environment variable `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` to something you do have (in my case, `Fusion`).

```
QApplication: invalid style override 'kvantum' passed, ignoring it.
    Available styles: Windows, Fusion"
```

Then your sample code is simply:

```
import cv2
import os

os.environ['QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE'] = 'Fusion'

img = cv2.imread('sample.jpg')
cv2.imshow("my_window", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score -1):

To me, the solution to this problem was removing Anaconda, then installing pip followed by installing OpenCV with a simple pip install command.