# Opencv-contrib installation error: file not found

Tags: python, opencv, pip, linux-mint, opencv-contrib

A Linux newbie here. On Linux Mint, python 3.8, under Anaconda, trying to install opencv-contrib-python by

```
pip install --no-binary opencv-contrib-python opencv-contrib-python
```

After a long and very resource-intensive process get this error. Any suggestions on what I am missing?
As a side note, normal pip installation without **--no-binary** works fine, but results in a runtime error that I am trying to resolve per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337870/python-opencv-error-current-thread-is-not-the-objects-thread).

```
  Configuring Project
    Working directory:
      /tmp/pip-install-cwq7rmvu/opencv-contrib-python/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.8/cmake-build
    Command:
      cmake /tmp/pip-install-cwq7rmvu/opencv-contrib-python/opencv -G Ninja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/tmp/pip-install-cwq7rmvu/opencv-contrib-python/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.8/cmake-install -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/home/artem/anaconda3/bin/python -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.8.5 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/artem/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/home/artem/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.8.so -DSKBUILD:INTERNAL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/tmp/pip-build-env-p4glm5l9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/home/artem/anaconda3/bin/python -DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/artem/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -DPYTHON3_LIBRARY=/home/artem/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.8.so -DBUILD_opencv_python3=ON -DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF -DOPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=python -DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON -DBUILD_opencv_apps=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_freetype=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/tmp/pip-install-cwq7rmvu/opencv-contrib-python/opencv_contrib/modules -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
  
  Copying files from CMake output
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/artem/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/artem/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/artem/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 204, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-p4glm5l9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 221, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-p4glm5l9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 207, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-p4glm5l9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 258, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-p4glm5l9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 496, in <module>
      main()
    File "setup.py", line 248, in main
      skbuild.setup(
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-p4glm5l9/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 625, in setup
      _classify_installed_files(cmake_manifest, package_data, package_prefixes,
    File "setup.py", line 381, in _classify_installed_files_override
      with open('scripts/__init__.py', 'r') as custom_init:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scripts/__init__.py'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-contrib-python
Failed to build opencv-contrib-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-contrib-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: always talk to the maintainers of those packages. in the case of your linux, that's the package maintained for your linux. in the case of the *binary* python package, make sure it's the latest version and **not** 3.4.something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing Anaconda and working with the python supplied with my Linux distro solved the issue.